# Weak convergence for strong survival of contact process

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

**EDIT:** Please see my attempt at a rough sketch to a solution in the edit below.

**Original post/question:**

I am interested in the general question of weak convergence of probability measures $\mu_n\Rightarrow \mu$, but my primary example of concern is the contact process.

Suppose we have the nearest neighbor contact process on $\mathbb Z^d$ with birth rate $\lambda$ and death rate $1$. Denote the state of the process at time $t\in[0,\infty)$ and site $x\in \mathbb Z^d$ by $\eta_t(x)$. At each site $x\in\mathbb Z^d$ we have transition rates $0\to1$ at rate $\lambda n_1$ with $$n_1=n_1(x,\eta_t)=|\{y : \eta_t(y)=1, ||x-y||_1=1\}|$$ being the number of nearest neighbors in state one (implicitly at time $t$), and $1\to0$ at rate $1$.

It is well-known that there is a critical value $\lambda_c$ (which depends on the dimension of the lattice) such that $\lambda>\lambda_c$ implies that the process survives strongly. This means that if the process is initiated with site $x$ occupied and all other sites empty, then there is a positive probability that site $x$ will be occupied infinitely often, which is denoted:
$$\mathbb P^{\{x\}}(\eta_t(x)=1 \text{ i.o.})>0.$$

It is also well-known that this is equivalent to a statement about the graphical construction where we envision "timelines extending upward" from each site in our integer lattice. Along each timeline we distribute $\times$ death marks at rate one and for each neighboring pair $x,y$ we distribute arrows from $x$ to $y$ and also from $y$ to $x$ each at rate $\lambda$. We say there is a path in the graph from $(x,s)$ to $(y,t)$ for $t\geq s$ if we can follow the "vertical" timelines upward from site $x$ at time $s$ never crossing any $\times$ mark but crossing arrows allowed and end up at site $y$ at time $t$. Then the probability of strong survival is equivalent to there being paths from $(x,0)$ to $(x,t)$ for infinitely many $t\in[0,\infty)$:
$$\mathbb P^{\{x\}}(\eta_t(x)=1 \text{ i.o.})=\mathbb P(\text{there is a path from $(x,0)$ to $(x,t)$ for infinitely many $t$}).$$

Suppose we are going to add an additional random factor here, that a site is either on or off. I will make it simple and just say that there is a probability that each site is on or off initially. Once a site is on, it stays on forever, and if it is initially off, then it flips on at rate $\beta$. Let $p$ be the probability a site is initially on, and let this be the same for every site. Hence $p=1$ gives us the standard contact process.

I'd like to be able to say that if all sites are initially off with $p=0$ then the process still survives strongly. This seems intuitively correct since we can pick and arbitrarily large time $T$ and an arbitrarily block with radius $M$ and say that there is a positive probability that at time $T$, all sites in the block $[-M,M]^d$ are on and that there have been no $\times$ marks for site $x$'s timeline. Hence we write
$$\begin{aligned}
\mathbb P^{\{x\}}&(\eta_t(x)=1 \text{ i.o.} \mid \text{ all sites initially off})\\
&\geq \mathbb P(\text{no $\times$ in $[0,T]$}) \\
&\qquad\cdot \mathbb P(\text{all sites $y\in[-M,M]^d$ on at time $T$}) \\
&\qquad\qquad\cdot \mathbb P^{\{x\}}(\eta_t(x)=1 \text{ i.o.} \mid \text{ all sites in $[-M,M]^d$ initially on, all others off})
\end{aligned}$$
So if I can show the last factor on the right is positive, then I am done. Intuitively, this clearly seems to be the case, since the block of sites that are on grows exponentially fast, but the contact process only grows linearly in time. Thus, with high probability, no path will use any timeline outside of $[-M,M]^d$ during the temporal interval $[0,T]$ when $M$ is large. The larger I choose $T$, the larger I can choose $M$, always keeping every factor on the right side in the above equation positive.

**Q1:** One of my questions is how to make rigorous the claim:
$$\mathbb P^{\{x\}}(\eta_t(x)=1 \text{ i.o.} \mid \text{ all sites in $[-M,M]^d$ initially on, all others off})>0.$$
Of course I am assuming that my reasoning above is solid, so please let me know if I am not thinking through this correctly here.

My other question is about weak convergence. Consider the process with all sites in $[-M,M]^d$ on and all others off for all time. So this is just the contact process on a finite grid. Clearly the probability of strong survival is always zero for any finite $M$. Although in some sense the distribution of this process converges to that of the process on the infinite lattice.

Let $\eta^M$ be the contact process indexed by $M$ (a sequence of contact processes indexed by $M$). The $M$ could represent the size of our finite grid as just described, or it could represent the probability that a site is initially on, e.g. $\eta^M$ has on probability $p_M=1-\frac1M$. My question is about what considerations I have we convergence of
$$\mathbb P^{\{x\}}(\eta^M_t(x)=1 \text{ i.o.})\to \mathbb P^{\{x\}}(\eta_t(x)=1 \text{ i.o.}) \quad \text{as} \quad M\to\infty.$$

**Q2:** What are the technical considerations that are important so that we have $\mathbb P^{\{x\}}(\eta^M_t(x)=1 \text{ i.o.})\to \mathbb P^{\{x\}}(\eta_t(x)=1 \text{ i.o.})$ as $M\to\infty$? I.e., what kinds of $\eta^M$ are allowed? Clearly, having $M$ represent a finite grid size doesn't work, but having it represent a probability of each site being initially on does seem to work. Thus having weak convergence of $\eta^M\overset{M\to\infty}\Longrightarrow \eta$ is not sufficient. Or maybe $\{\eta_t(x)=1 \text{ i.o.}\}$ is simply not a continuity set for the contact process? Or maybe I am just misunderstanding something structural here, e.g. that the space of path realizations or the space of infinite graphs are not separable/complete or that the metric on these spaces would "tamp out" faraway times and sites, thus making the "infinitely many paths" event problematic in some way?

**EDIT: My new answer attempt (a rough sketch):**
The contact process with all sites initially off still has a positive probability of survival when started from a single initially infected site (strong survival). This can be seen using the comparison to oriented percolation. We know that the standard supercritical contact process dominates a supercritical oriented percolation. I won't try to reproduce the details here though. For this domination we just need a large enough spacetime box so that the probability of there being enough infection paths from the bottom to the top of the box so that the infection can be transmitted from this spacetime box to the next spacetime box with very high probability. Assume we have such a comparison to percolation for the standard contact process. Now choose $M$ large enough so that the contact process with all sites in $[-M,M]^d$ initially on (and all others off), is identical to the standard contact process on the large spacetime box. Also choose $T$ large enough (the temporal dimension of the large spacetime box) so that the contact process at time $T$ (and beyond) is arbitrarily close the process with sites initially off. Basically the idea is to make $T$ large enough so that with high probability enough sites are on at time $T$ to make the graphical structures of this process and the standard contact process very close (i.e. the latter has very few if any additional infection arrows). Then we can show that the probability a large spacetime box being "wet" (for the percolation comparison) for the process of interest (for all relevant spacetime boxes) is within some $\epsilon$ of the same probability for the standard contact process. Since the latter is supercritical, we can make the probability of wet for the former sufficiently large so that it dominates a supercritical oriented percolation. Thus the process with all sites initially off survives strongly.

**Request:** I would love some feedback if this attempt is even remotely correct. If it seems correct, then I just need to formalize it.

This doesn't answer my question about weak convergence, but it makes me think the answer is yes, at least in this particular instance, though I would still like some insight into the more general case.